# Full product addition in 'try catch'

Tags: product

I'm saving a product like this (because this how I've `learned` it)

```
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->[do a lot of stuff for adding a product];
try {
    $product->save(); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    __error($e);
}
```

But this could `still` have errors while adding the product.

So now I'm doing:

```
try {
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->[do a lot of stuff for adding a product];
    $product->save(); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    __error($e);
}
```

Is this a correct way of handling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct or wrong way of doing this. 
It depends what errors are you trying to catch.
For example I would put all the code inside a `try-catch` statement to catch all the exceptions.
And a suggestion: Don't use `$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();`. Instead use 
`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`. It's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marius<p>One question though; would it be possible to validate it before I do ->save()?

Comment: You have the methods `$product->validate();` available. See what that does.